# Needing To Meet Multiple Conditions using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, json

Ok, so think of a site where the user is allowed to enter in multiple search parameters for looking up nearby restaurants. Not a novel concept, but the issue I am running into is using SQL and PHP to output JSON arrays meeting multiple conditions.

For example, User searches by distance and/or price and/or whether restaurant offers dine-in, takeout and/or delivery. If user does not specifiy a genre it searches all genres. Well, the issue here is that those are not the results I will get. If I use price, then multiple genres show up even though I specify "Japanese" I will still get American, or Fast Food, BBQ, etc... But then if I sort by rating like I have, then the prices will not sort appropriately if user wants to look for expensive restaurants ($$$$ passes a "1", $$$ = 2 and so on where 4 is the cheapest restaurant pricing), it might show a lower price rating first since the rating is higher than that of the expensive price rank the user chose to search for... sigh. How can I expect to meet all these conditions? Any ideas? Suggestions? Thanks!!

Here is My PHP with SQL statements:

```
switch ($rest_genre) {
    case '':
        $query = "SELECT rest_id,user_id,rest_name,lat,lng,rest_price,rest_rating,rest_genre,eat_in,take_out,delivery,
        3959.0 * 5280.0 * acos(sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat))
        + cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat))
        * cos(radians(lng) - radians(?))) as distance
        FROM food_locations
        WHERE rest_price >= ? AND eat_in = ? OR take_out = ? OR delivery = ?
        HAVING distance <= $radius
        ORDER BY rest_rating DESC";

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("sssiiii",$lat,$lat,$lng,$rest_price,$eat_in,$take_out,$delivery);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($rest_id,$user_id,$rest_name,$lat,$lng,$rest_price,$rest_rating,$rest_genre,$eat_in,$take_out,$delivery,$distance);
            $stmt->store_result();
            //fetch all records as they exist per filter
            if( $stmt->num_rows() > 0 ) {
                while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
                    $row = array(
                        'restID' => $rest_id,
                        'userID' => $user_id,
                        'rest_name' => $rest_name,
                        'lat' => $lat,
                        'lng' => $lng,
                        'restPrice' => $rest_price,
                        'restRating' => $rest_rating,
                        'restGenre' => $rest_genre,
                        'eat_in' => $eat_in,
                        'take_out' => $take_out,
                        'delivery' => $delivery,
                        'distance' => $distance);

                     $rows['restaurants'][] = $row;
                     $rows['error'] .= $mysqli->error;
                }
                echo json_encode($rows);
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('restaurants' => '', 'error' => $mysqli->error));
            }
            //alternative: echo json_encode(array_merge($rows, $errArray));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => $mysqli->error));
        }
        break;
    default:
        $query = "SELECT rest_id,user_id,rest_name,lat,lng,rest_price,rest_rating,rest_genre,eat_in,take_out,delivery,
        3959.0 * 5280.0 * acos(sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat))
        + cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat))
        * cos(radians(lng) - radians(?))) as distance
        FROM food_locations
        WHERE rest_price >= ? AND rest_genre = ? AND eat_in = ? OR take_out = ? OR delivery = ?
        HAVING distance <= $radius
        ORDER BY rest_rating DESC";

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("sssisiii",$lat,$lat,$lng,$rest_price,$rest_genre,$eat_in,$take_out,$delivery);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($rest_id,$user_id,$rest_name,$lat,$lng,$rest_price,$rest_rating,$rest_genre,$eat_in,$take_out,$delivery,$distance);
            $stmt->store_result();
            //fetch all records as they exist per filter
            if( $stmt->num_rows() > 0 ) {
                while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
                    $row = array(
                        'restID' => $rest_id,
                        'userID' => $user_id,
                        'rest_name' => $rest_name,
                        'lat' => $lat,
                        'lng' => $lng,
                        'restPrice' => $rest_price,
                        'restRating' => $rest_rating,
                        'restGenre' => $rest_genre,
                        'eat_in' => $eat_in,
                        'take_out' => $take_out,
                        'delivery' => $delivery,
                        'distance' => $distance);

                     $rows['restaurants'][] = $row;
                     $rows['error'] .= $mysqli->error;
                }
                echo json_encode($rows);
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('restaurants' => '', 'error' => $mysqli->error));
            }
            //alternative: echo json_encode(array_merge($rows, $errArray));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => $mysqli->error));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand, simplest method is to just count how many of the conditions were actually met, then sort by that derived value, e.g.

```
SELECT IF(rest_price >= ?, 1, 0) + IF(rest_genre = ?, 1, 0) + more conditions
  + translate distance into score + other conditions ...  AS score
....
ORDER BY score desc
```

It'd be an ugly query, but would give you the top scoring locations first. Of course, you could just fetch the raw values into PHP and do the scoring calculations there, then sort your results array by that score as well.

Comment: great direction, thanks. I will play around with the SELECT IF + function too. Never used those.

Comment: Ok after some extensive testing I don't think that is what I am look for after all... If we look at the WHERE clause, I actually need it to work so that the eatin, takeout and delivery options are able to be pulled up when all three of those values are "1" meaning the user is searching for ANY and ALL restaurants with those service options. However the record in database will not be found if delivery is set to 0, since the search will yield only if the record has delivery set to 1. I tried using the OR statements in the where clause but that doesn't work well as the rest_genre will be ignored.

Comment: So far I am using WHERE rest_price >= ? AND eat_in = ? AND take_out = ? AND delivery = ? but of course that will only return a record if it matches those exact service options. The idea is the user will say "I want to see all restaurants with an eat in and/or delivery options." So if a record has delivery, but not eat in, it should still show up in results in this way. So yeh, it's annoying, I am dealing with a case that is either/or AND both/and... not sure how I need to tackle this with SQL or PHP. My iOS developer passes the strings to my PHP file.